# How to share text on Facebook using Facebook SDK in Android

Tags: android, facebook, android-activity

How to share text on **Facebook** from an Android app using the Android **facebook sdk**?

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look a look on my library: 
[here](https://github.com/antonkrasov/AndroidSocialNetworks)

With help of it, posting is really easy:

```
mSocialNetworkManager.getFacebookSocialNetwork().postMessage(String message)
mSocialNetworkManager.getFacebookSocialNetwork().postPhoto(File path...)
```

Comment: OAuthActivity Project i can test but error shown java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidsocialnetworks.lib/com.androidsocialnetworks.lib.OAuthActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: required PARAM_URL_TO_LOAD @Gautham Kumar